# How diagrams with loop and several propagators contribute to $S$-matrix element?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, feynman-diagrams, s-matrix-theory

I studied Feynman rules with Schwartz textbook and what caught my eye was diagrams such as second and third on this picture (diagrams to the second order of $g$ for $\mathcal{L} = \frac{g}{3!}\phi^3$ interaction)

[[image: Diagrams for <span class=]$\mathcal{L} = \frac{g}{3!}\phi^3$ interaction. Schwartz picture 7.23" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPPJD.png)

I'm very interested in how such kind of diagrams as second and especially third contribute to the final $S$-matrix element. Do they look any different for momentum space, or they should just get canceled for violation of momentum conservation?

Comment: What makes you think it violates momentum conservation? There will be a momentum conserving delta function if you calculate the amplitude.

Comment: @Obama2020, the last diagram got dead end. The momentum going from x to y must disappear some way

Comment: These are the tadpole diagrams and they are cancelled by the $\phi^1$ counter term.

Comment: @PeterKravchuk, can you please be more specific about $\phi^1$ counter term? Which term is that and where it came from? Is that from renormalization? I'm sorry, I'm just starting to understand this subject

Comment: This is the phi to the power one counter term in the action. It is just one of the counter terms possible in your theory since no symmetry excludes it. Sredniki's textbook contains a simple discussion of it, as far as I remember.